# SQLITE ORDE BY DATE

Tags: sqlite, sorting, date, format

i have a column type text for date in this format"dd/mm/YYYY". How can i do to order by this column?

Comment: The best solution is to change the column type to `date`

Comment: @juergend SQLite has no datatype of type `date`. It will accept integerrs or strings. If you specify `DATE`, SQLite will use the **TEXT** datatype, for affinity. The OP must insert the dates in the correct **format**. I,e.; `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the database engine to do the sorting, you will need to convert your data format to one recognized by the SQLITE engine

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
DDDDDDDDDD
```